# Instantianting objects in clojure

Tags: clojure

I am very very new to clojure so i would like to code it in java.

What i have is this current code. But it seems to throw a CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't take value of a macro: #'clojure.core/->, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:2)

moreover, it seems to instantiate only one object

```
(defrecord Learning [Name Age Gender])
  (def person 
    (apply -> Learning
           (clojure.string/split
             "Jon,12,Male", #",")
           )
    )
```

However, what i would like to do is to code this in java.
For example in Java we would have a class like

```
Public class Person {
Private int age;
Private String Gender;
Private String Name;

Person(String Name, String gender, int age)
{
this.name = Name;
this.age = age;
this.Gender = gender;
}
}

To Instantiate an instance of this class we would have a line like 

Person Jon = new Person(Jon, Male, 12);
```

How would i do it in clojure?

I have this

```
(defn update [x]
  (def person 
    (apply ->Learning
           (clojure.string/split
             x, #",")
           )
    )
)
```

But it says its a malformed expression. What i am trying to do is like making a constructor in java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid compiler error just remove space between `->` and `Lerning`

```
(def person (apply ->Learning
                   (clojure.string/split
                    "Jon,12,Male", #",")))
```

and it'll work

```
person
-> Learning{:Name "Jon", :Age "12", :Gender "Male"}
```